# Unresolved reference Issue in Android Gradle Kotlin Dsl

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

i migrated my gradle file to kotlin dsl from groovy. Everything works fine but there is a problem with improting values to gradle from another kotlin file. I can import variables and autocomplete just works fine but when i build project, it gives me **Unresolved reference** error.
Appreciate any help.

Gradle version : 7.1.1

Android studio : Arctic Fox

build.gradle.kts that i created under buildSrc :

```
plugins {
    `java-gradle-plugin`
    `kotlin-dsl`
    `kotlin-dsl-precompiled-script-plugins`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

File that i import from in buildSrc/src/main/java/Dependencies :

```
object Versions {
    const val compose_version = "1.0.0"
}

object Dependencies {
    const val compose_ui = "androidx.compose.ui:ui:${Versions.compose_version}"
    const val compose_material = "androidx.compose.material:material:${Versions.compose_version}"
    const val compose_ui_tooling_preview = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:${Versions.compose_version}"
    const val compose_ui_tooling = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:${Versions.compose_version}"
    const val compose_ui_test = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:${Versions.compose_version}"
}
```

app build.gradle.kts file :

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("android")
}

android {
    compileSdk = 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.compose"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 30
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            isDebuggable = true
        }
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isDebuggable = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility(JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8)
        targetCompatibility(JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8)
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.0.0"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0")

    // Jetpack Compose
     implementation(Dependencies.compose_ui)
     implementation(Dependencies.compose_material)
     implementation(Dependencies.compose_ui_tooling_preview)
     debugImplementation(Dependencies.compose_ui_tooling)
     androidTestImplementation(Dependencies.compose_ui_test)

    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said that your other file is under `buildSrc/src/main/java/Dependencies`. Since this is a Kotlin file, it should be `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Dependencies` instead.